# jQuery dataTables - Sorting currency format not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using Datatables to sort my tables.
Some of my columns contains currency data. Example :

```
1 $
12 $
12 345 $
2 123 $
```

Because of the space in some values, Datatables consider the column containing strings, and not numbers, so the sort is not correct
See plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/QU7lIK7pWUfyw6PU5a3H?p=preview

Is there a way to make it sort these data correctly ? And yes, if possible, without having to define it for each column, i have 20 tables, with plenty of currency columns, i don't want to define it for each table, thanks

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to create an adequate plugin yourself. The default sorting algorithm cannot take care of malformed or none typical content. But this is very easy. The following plugin sorts your special currencies correctly :

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "my-currency-pre": function(a) {
        return parseFloat(a.replace(/ /gi, ''));
    },
    "my-currency-asc": function(a,b) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },
    "my-currency-desc": function(a,b) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
});
```

usage :

```
var table = $('#example').dataTable({
   "aoColumnDefs": [
      {"sType": "my-currency", "aTargets": [0]}
   ]
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/8kez8mvy/** (the table from your plnkr)

It works by removing the whitespace and ignoring the $ sign before the values are compared. As for "*i don't want to define it for each table, thanks*", well - I am afraid you must - sorting special data with special measures sometimes need special coding :)

Comment: Thanks, it works on your example, but when i tried it on my own table, it doesn't work :( http://jsfiddle.net/8kez8mvy/ i'm i missing something ? (see column "montant") thanks

Comment: hey @user - The <table> in the fiddle is the same as you have in the plnkr.  Can you edit the fiddle with the rows/ table you are not having success with? Remember to declare the plugin before you initialize the datatable!

Comment: oups, sorry, i just didn't provide the right link,  i'll give you the right link in a moment, thanks a lot

Comment: @user, it is still the same link you are pasting :) you can change the HTML in the fiddle, then click "update", then post the address link here in a comment.

Comment: Here is the right link http://jsfiddle.net/8kez8mvy/1/ i have multiple columns, in your fiddle, even when i add columns it still work, but in my example, it's just not working :/

Comment: @user - oh yes, You need to define which columns the sorting plugin should be attached to in the initialization - in your case (the updated fiddle) is it the columns 3,4,5,6 and 7 - so `{"sType": "my-currency", "aTargets": [3,4,5,6,7]}` instead of  `{"sType": "my-currency", "aTargets": [0]}` see 
**http://jsfiddle.net/8kez8mvy/3/**